How to custom chain to uniswap interface v3 with swap token?
I encountered an issue when customizing the chain and received the error:
{
"detail": ""tokenInChainId" must be one of [1, 5, 10, 56, 137, 324, 8453, 42161, 42220, 43114, 44787, 80001, 81457, 84531, 421613, 7777777, 11155111]",
"errorCode": "VALIDATION_ERROR"
}
when calling getQuote in uniswap v3 interface

You need to provide more details: repository used, version, changes made.
